# Apply Css to Auto Complete li's based on condition?

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to add a `css` to list items based on the condition which is , if a list item's `label` text contains `+` i need to add red color else i just need to add yellow background-color .

I am almost there but i have no clue to access `dynamic data coming form server` in my `open` function .

**Code :**

```
$("#project").autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: function (request, response) {
            //In success of ajax call i fill request(projects)
            response(projects);
        },
        open: function (event, ui) {
            var len = $('.ui-autocomplete > li').length;
            //I can access projects here but i need filtered data list coming from server which is passed to response callback
            $('.ui-autocomplete > li').css("background-color", "yellow");

            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                // Here i use indexof('+') on each list item's label text and apply css but how to get the list here ??
            }

            $('#count').html('Founded ' + len + ' results');
        }
    });
```

Check the fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/DZ9zU/34/)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method with a function to return color based on the text content:

```
open: function (event, ui) {
    $('.ui-autocomplete > li').css("background-color", function() {
        return $(this).text().indexOf('+') > -1 ? 'red' : 'yellow';
    });
    $('#count').html('Founded ' + len + ' results');
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/DZ9zU/35/

I would also recommend to set a class name instead of inline css styles, this gives better flexibility in terms of styling.

```
open: function (event, ui) {
    $('.ui-autocomplete > li:contains(+)').addClass('red');
    $('#count').html('Founded ' + len + ' results');
}
```

with CSS rules:

```
.ui-autocomplete > li {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.ui-autocomplete > li.red {
    background-color: red;
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/DZ9zU/36/

Comment: yes , will use class name which is appropriate . Thanks again for the tip .

Comment: how can we access the value and check condition in `open` event . fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/DZ9zU/37/ . please check the comment . cheers

Answer (score 1):

Another approach to customize the item display is to use [_renderItem](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-_renderItem)

```
$("#project").autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    source: function (request, response) {
        //In success of ajax call i fill request(projects)
        response(projects);
    },
    open: function (event, ui) {
        //do what else you want to do
    }
}).data('autocomplete')._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
    return $("<li>")
        .attr("data-value", item.value)
        .addClass(/\+/.test(item.label) ? 'plus' : '')
        .append(item.label)
        .appendTo(ul);
};
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wx2201xg/)

Comment: fiddle seems to display fine but i am unable to select any option ? any idea Arun .